# Python 3 centered triangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to hone my Python 3 (specifically, nested loops) with the good old triangle exercises (which only takes an odd input for now). However, I have come across a problem I can't warp my head around with.

```
user_input = 7
x = 1
temp = user_input
spaces = " "
stars = ""
y = temp - 2
t = 0
while x < temp:
    while y > t:
        stars = "*" * x
        spaces = spaces * y
        print(spaces + stars)
        spaces= " "
        y -= 1
        x += 2
```

I have a `user_input` (which is 7 for now so I don't have to give an input each time I run).

A variable `x` and `t` used for the `while` loop

Another `temp`orary variable that holds my `user_input` (in case I decrement it as not to 'damage' the original variable).

A variable `spaces` and another variable `stars` (which should be self explanatory as I'm trying to draw a triangle based on asterisks).

I have a variable `y` which is equal to `temp - 2`

Expected output of 7 should be like this:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
```

The reason I have made `y` equal to `temp - 2` is because the first row has spaces equal to `user_input - 2`.

So let's say our input was 7, first row's amount of spaces is 5.

If our input is 9, first row's amount of spaces is 7

The first `while` loop will loop from 1 to 7 (1, 3 , 5, 7) which is why I made `x` equal to `1`.

The second `while` loop should loop from `input - 2` until 0.

Weird thing is, that if my `user_input` is equal to `5`, it outputs just how I expected it to be.

```
   *
  ***
 *****
```

But once I enter something like `7`, it builds a triangle from 1 to 9 (1, 3, 5, 7, 9)

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

But I expect it to end right before the last row, it should output as many asterisks as my input.

Is my thought process wrong? If so, where did I end up wrong?

I hope I have clarified everything as much as possible.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Is your input (`user_input`) guaranteed to always be odd? If not, what should happen if it is even?

Comment: @G_M Yes. This program is only able to take odd inputs (for now) I plan to broaden my program into taking even inputs as well once I'm done with the odd part for now. I figured that I should split the problems into "sub problems" first :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems overly complicated. Why not just:

```
input = 7
i = 1
while i <= input:
    spaces = ' ' * ((input-i) // 2) 
    stars = '*' * i
    print(spaces + stars)
    i += 2 

   *
  ***
 *****
*******
```

Or even simpler, using `str.center`:

```
while i <= input:
    print(('*' * i).center(input))
    i += 2
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid ´for´ loops and functions. I'm concentrating on  nested ´while´ loops. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: @KoyaCho Edited my answer. Removed convenience function and changed for to while loop ;)

Comment: May I ask why you are dividing by 2 each time in the loop? :)

Comment: The last line contains `input` stars, and as you go up you replace stars with spaces. But you actually print only the spaces before the remaining stars, so half of them, hence the dividing by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify a bit your code a bit :

- `t` is useless since it holds only 0 and never changes, use 0 instead
- `user_input` is never used except to make `temp = user_input`, use `user_input` instead of temp. As for decrementing it, it doesn't happen, and anyway you never return it to the user so it would be ok.
- that's kind of a typo so it's ok, but avoid letting your debugging prints like `print(x,y)` when you show some code on Stack Overflow, it's harder for us to understand the whole code.
- If you change back `spaces = " "` at the end of the `while`, just use `spaces = " " * y`.
- You do nothing between the two `while` so you can "merge" them with an `and` on conditions.

So now we have :

```
user_input = 9
x = 1
y = user_input - 2
while x < user_input and y > 0:
    stars = "*" * x
    spaces = " " * y
    print(spaces + stars)
    y -= 1
    x += 2
```

As you can see, you have two stopping conditions on your `while` when only one would be clearer. The reason behind your code works with 7 and not more is because 7 is the limit between when one condition stops loop and when the other does.

I would suggest to change your code to :

```
user_input = 3
x = 0
while x < user_input//2:
    stars = "*" * (x * 2 + 1)
    spaces = " " * (user_input//2 - x)
    print(spaces + stars)
    x += 1
```

Comment: My apologies about the typo! I have removed it as per requested.
On a different note, how would you go about it using nested `while` loops? 

Thanks a bunch, Baptiste!

Comment: What do you mean by using nested while loop? The only way to use another loop here is to add a useless one, or to find a case like `while <something working for the n first steps> while <something working for the other steps>` so I do not think you should do it.

Comment: A general rule in programming is **Simple is better than complicated** so if you can do it with only one loop instead of two, most of the time it is better to use only one. But for a more general case, sometime it is necessary to use nested loops, even if the lesser the better.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in your code. Here is the rectified code.

```
user_input = 7
x = 1
temp = user_input
spaces = " "
stars = ""
y = temp - 2
t = 0
while x <= temp:
    stars = "*" * x
    spaces = spaces * y
    print(spaces + stars)
    spaces= " "
    y -= 1
    x += 2
```

It is not necessary to check `y>0` since your first while loop is enough to meet the requirement. Because of that extra `while loop` you are getting ambiguous values of `(x,y)`.

Comment: I was talking about the values of x and y which you are using to print the stars and spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The lazy solution using the builtin [`center()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) and the [format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
user_input = [5,7,9]

def getStars(num):
    return ('*' * i for i in range(1,num+1,2))

def sol1(num):
    for s in getStars(num):
        print(s.center(num)) 

def sol2(num):
    stars = getStars(num)

    for s in stars:
        print( ("{:^"+str(num)+"}").format(s))

for s in user_input:
    sol1(s)
    sol2(s)
```

Output:

```
  *  
 *** 
*****
  *  
 *** 
*****
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
   *   
  ***  
 ***** 
*******
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```